# Adding empty line between text groups by separated prefix

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to sort and group certain programming statements in ascending order for easier readability of the source code. So far I could extract these programming statements and sort them in ascending order by using `sort`.

A few examples:

```
# Example 1
keyword ABC;
keyword ABC.DEF;
keyword ABC.GHI;
keyword ABC.JKL.MNO;
keyword ZYX;
keyword ZYX.RST;
keyword ZYX.WVU;

# Example 2
keyword ABC;
keyword ABC.DEF;
keyword ABC.GHI;
keyword ABC.JKL.MNO;

# Example 3
keyword ZYX;
keyword ZYX.RST;
keyword ZYX.WVU;
```

Each line starts with `keyword`, followed by a space and a text that could be separated in several parts by a period. I would like to add a empty line between the last line starting with `keyword ABC` and the first line starting with `keyword ZYX`. But it is not guaranteed that there will be at least one line starting with `keyword ABC` and one line starting with `keyword ZYX`.

Comment: So what do you want if there's no such line?

Comment: @daniu Then no empty line should be inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using GNU sed and the files are short enough, an easy solution to do multiline substitution is to use the `-z` flag :

```
sed -zE 's/(keyword ABC[^\n]*\n)(keyword ZYX)/\1\n\2/'
```

The `-z` flag is there to make `sed` ignore linefeeds and use `\0` as the records separator, so that your whole file is read as a single record (which is why they should not be too large) and `\n` can be matched. We then substitute two consecutive lines "keyword ABC" and "keyword ZYX" by adding an extra linefeed between them.

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/rU2rXm).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the lines are put in a file named `input.txt`, the following code will solve the problem:

```
last_first="0";
cat input.txt | while read line; do
    text=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}');
    first=${text:0:1}
    if [ "$last_first" = "0" ]; then
        last_first="$first";
    elif [ "$last_first" != "$first" ]; then
        echo;
        last_first="$first";
    fi
    echo $text; 
done
```